# How can I specify the last column of a tibble within the rename_with() function's ".cols" argumnt in Dyplr?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Given a tibble "cars"

```
cars |>
  rename_with(~paste0(.x, ")"), .cols = (2:10))
```

appends a parenthesis to the names columns 2 to 10 of the tibble. How would one go about selecting from the second to the last column? I have accomplished it with

```
rename_with(~paste0(.x, ")"), .cols = (2:ncol(betterLifeIndicators)))
```

but I am sure there must be a more elegant way to do it within the dyplr package. I was also wondering if there is a way to select all columns except the first (or any other specified set).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me know if this works.

```
# Last column
cars |> 
  rename_with(~paste0(.x, ")"), .cols = last_col())

# 2nd to Last column
cars |> 
  rename_with(~paste0(.x, ")"), .cols = 2:last_col())

# All but first (same as above)
cars |> 
  rename_with(~paste0(.x, ")"), .cols = -1)
```

Comment: All of the above work flawlessly, thank you very much. It seems that last_col() really is the way to go.